# Реферальные хвосты на MODX EVO

Tags: modx

Друзья! Не подскажете, как сделать отправку реферальных хвостов на Modx Evo?
Скрипт завел,

```
<style display: none> <input type="text" name="fefers" class="refer" value=""></style>
```

в callback-tpl прописал.
$fefers  = $_POST['fefers']; в конфиг добавил. Хвост приходит пустой(заходил с директа)
Возможно я где-то фатально ошибся. Подскажите!